# MediaPipe selfie segmentation: Getting error when trying to capture stream from canvas

Tags: javascript, mediapipe, segmentationselfie

I'm trying to use selfie segmentation on the image from my webcam. For this, I'm using the MediaPipe lib.

Here is my code

```
const selfieSegmentation = new SelfieSegmentation({locateFile: (file) => {
    return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/selfie_segmentation/${file}`;
}});
selfieSegmentation.setOptions({
    modelSelection: 1,
});
selfieSegmentation.onResults(handleSegmentationResults);

videoElement.addEventListener('playing', function () {
    selfieSegmentation.send({image: this})
})
```

Here is where I get the segmentation result and draw the canvas:

```
const videoElement = document.getElementById('myVideo');
const canvasElement = document.getElementsByClassName('output_canvas')[0];
const controlsElement = document.getElementsByClassName('control-panel')[0];
const canvasCtx = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
const img = document.getElementById('vbackground');

function handleSegmentationResults(results) {
    canvasCtx.save();

    canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
    canvasCtx.globalCompositeOperation =  'source-in'; 
    canvasCtx.drawImage(results.image, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);

    // // Make all pixels not in the segmentation mask transparent
    canvasCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
    canvasCtx.drawImage(results.segmentationMask, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);

    canvasCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
    canvasCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);

    canvasCtx.restore();
    //here is where I'm getting the error
    const canvasStream = canvasCtx.canvas.captureStream();
}
```

I want to capture the canvas stream so that I can place it on my video element. But when I try to use the method canvasCtx.canvas.captureStream(), I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'captureStream' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Canvas is not origin-clean.
> at eval (eval at handleSegmentationResults (http://localhost:3000/js/host.js:1570:9), :1:18)
> at handleSegmentationResults (http://localhost:3000/js/host.js:1570:9)
> at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/selfie_segmentation/selfie_segmentation.js:88:322

Does anyone know another way to capture the stream or what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: have you been able to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

**handleSegmentationResults** executes each time when result of segmentation returns something

I suppose that the first of all you need to move **canvasStream** outside of this function

Also, you might use **canvasElement** itself to capture the stream